# Combining Visual Studio 2010 workspace with Visual Studio 2013 workspace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, tfs, source-control-explorer

My team uses a Team Foundation Server (TFS) to house code for multiple websites and custom libraries shared by all of those websites. For our newest website, we work in VS2013, but one older website has compatibility issues unless you open it in VS2010. Generally, this is fine.

Recently, however, I ran into source control issues that I realized was the result of accidentally adding a `.csproj` from my VS2013 workspace into the old website's `.sln` in VS2010.

While I was eventually able to sort out this discrepancy, I'm curious if there is a way to, or a reason to, combine or associate my VS2010 workspace and my VS2013 workspace seeing as they are both representing the same branch on our TFS?

*Disclaimer: I am new to TFS, .NET and Visual Studio so please quietly disregard this question if it's dumb.*

Comment: "workspace" is not a term in the Visual Studio glossary. Do you mean Solution or a Project or something else? Also note that generally VS2013 is a complete replacement for VS2010 (i.e. there is no reason to be running VS2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted solution to your issue is separation rather than consolidation. If you pull out your shared code to a separate solution and have it built into a Nuget package then you reference that package from both 2010 & 2013.

However as Visual Studio 2010 drops out of mainstream support next month you should also resolve the compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Didn't realize 2010 was losing support. That will probably convince others of the need to sort through the compatibility problems.